# os.walk not saving images in sub directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, os.walk

`Images` is a folder which have 10 more sub folders and every sub folder have one image which i am resizing and saving on same place but `os.walk` is not working can anyone check what i did wrong.

```
path='E:/Dataset_Final/Images/'
def count_em(path):
    for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(path)):
        for file_ in files:
            full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_)
            print (full_file_path)
            img = Image.open(full_file_path)
            new_width  = 32
            new_height = 32
            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save(os.path.join(root, file_+''),'png')
        return 
count_em(path)
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any stack-trace we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `return` after the first directory.

Remove the return statement and your code should work as expected.